# Entity Framework Core creating db hasComputedCollumn with user function how to configure?

Tags: entity-framework, calculated-columns

In db I would like to have  funcition dbo.fGetTreePath
and use that function in computed column.

When db is created I can add function through SQL, but

How to configure OnModelCreating etc to make computed column with function/db that does not exist yet?

Do not attach has computed column and add the column by correcting the script in migration?
Is there any other way to do this relatively clear/good way?

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Location>().Property(p => p.HierarchyPath).HasComputedColumnSql("dbo.fGetTreePath([Id])");  // gives error  as there is no that function yet.
```